# Removing lines from Polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to remove streets that I have as a line vector from a Polygon. I already tried the cutting tool  and the difference tool
both didn't work, I only received the Streets were cut out. I already tried making the line vector a single string with no difference.

Is there another way of solving this problem or do I need to find the issue of the cutting tool (which is most likely my own fault) ?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines have no width/area, hence you can't substract them from your polygon. Buffer your roads by a realistic value, then run the difference tool with the polygon as first input, and your buffered streets as the second.